# Unexpected behavior when using YAML Storage with TinyDB

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, tinydb

I'm using TinyDB for a small CLI utility to manage personal document drafts. The database stores metadata for each draft; the file should be human-editable (so that I can add details manually), and for this reason I'd like to use YAML over JSON as the format.

I implemented a `YamlStorage` class subclassing `storages.Storage` as indicated in the TinyDB docs:

```
class TestYamlStorage(Storage):
    """
    Store the data in a YAML file.
    Written following the example at http://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extend.html#write-a-custom-storage
    """
    def __init__(self, filename):  # (1)
        super().__init__()
        self.filename = filename
        touch(filename)

    def read(self):
        with open(self.filename) as handle:
            try:
                data = yaml.load(handle.read())
                return data
            except yaml.YAMLError:
                return None  # (3)

    def write(self, data):
        print('writing data: {}'.format(data))
        with open(self.filename, 'w') as handle:
                yaml.dump(data, handle)


    def close(self):  # (4)
        pass
```

Everything works fine when inserting only one element, or multiple elements at the same time using `insert_multiple`:

```
db = TinyDB('db.yaml', storage=TestYamlStorage)
dicts = [
    dict(name='Homer', age=38),
    dict(name='Marge', age=34),
    dict(name='Bart', age=10)
]

# this works as expected
db.insert_multiple(dicts)
```

The resulting `db.yaml`:

```
_default:
  1: {age: 38, name: Homer}
  2: {age: 34, name: Marge}
  3: {age: 10, name: Bart}
```

However, when inserting elements multiple times with `insert`, the resulting YAML file is different:

```
db = TinyDB('db.yaml', storage=TestYamlStorage)

db.insert(dict(name='Homer', age=38))
db.insert(dict(name='Bart', age=10))
```

`db.yaml`:

```
_default:
  1: !!python/object/new:tinydb.database.Element
    dictitems: {age: 38, name: Homer}
    state: {eid: 1}
  2: {age: 10, name: Bart}
```

The data in this format (apart from looking messier) seems to be not compatible with `yaml.safe_load` (calling `db.all()` returns `[]`). My interpretation is that the YAML serialization process is in some way "over-eager", i.e. that the `Element` instance gets written to `db.yaml` instead of the underlying data.

Is there something wrong with my code? I've tried to fiddle with PyYAML options, using a different YAML module (ruamel.yaml), and create a second YamlStorage class copying from the default JSONStorage, but without any difference.

Version info: Python 3.4.3, TinyDB 3.2.0, PyYAML 3.11. I posted a  runnable MWE with all imports [here](https://gist.github.com/fndari/f6885b336359370d4afbd5a9340316cb).

## Edit

After @Anthon's suggestion, I tried printing the YAML output to `sys.stdout` immediately before dumping to file. The problem is reproduced also in this case. See [notebook](https://gist.github.com/fndari/bc4d724a52c9d4b1152ea1a2e5a5ffed).

Answer (score 0):

When you update an existing "database" you retrieve a `database.Element` which includes (as you can see in the second YAML file) state information.

When that again is saved you are not saving a `dict`,  but an instance of this `Element` which is a subclass of `dict` and for that `ruamel.yaml` (and PyYAML) needs to store both the `dictitems` (the key value pairs for the `dict`) and the `state` (a dictionary representing that attributes and their values).

Converting your Element to a `dict` explicitly before writing should do the trick:

```
    def write(self, data):
        print('writing data: {}'.format(data))
        with open(self.filename, 'w') as handle:
                yaml.dump(dict(data), handle)
    #                      ^^^^    ^
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a difference. If it can be relevant, `print(type(data))` before the call to `yaml.dump` returns `<class 'dict'>`.

Comment: I would rather do a YAML dump of that with `stream=sys.stdout`, so you can see what YAML thinks it is getting.

Comment: I added a link to a notebook to my question with the dump to `sys.stdout`.